# Jetty Reactive Client version update from 1.1.14 to 2.0.8 ClassNotFound

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jetty

I updated the jetty version because of the vulnerabilities, from 1.1.14 to 2.0.8. It has the same dependencies as far as i see on jetty-util.

If i run the project i have an error:

```
WARN 72142 --- [   scheduling-1] reactor.core.Exceptions                  : throwIfFatal detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/AutoLock
    at org.eclipse.jetty.reactive.client.internal.AbstractSinglePublisher
```

```
1.1.14:
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-reactive-httpclient:jar:1.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.51.v20230217:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.51.v20230217:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.51.v20230217:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.51.v20230217:compile
```

````
2.0.8:
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-reactive-httpclient:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.51.v20230217:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.51.v20230217:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.51.v20230217:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.51.v20230217:compile```
````

Why? how can i resolve this?

tried all of the versions, checked the dependencies.

maven clean, clean install, all the versions, include util.

Comment: Spring Boot manages the version of Jetty, you cannot simply update it as that will also lead to compatibility issues with Spring (Boot). You probably need to upgrade to a newer spring boot version.